# Программа странно работает

Tags: c++

столкнулся с тем, что у меня программа работает неправильно если я "просто" запускаю её на выполнение. Но если поставить в IDE брейкпоинты, то она работает нормально. Реализую список с пропусками и для теста просто заполняю его числами от 1 до 10. Если запускаю "просто", то получается это:

```
lvl 0 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
lvl 1 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
lvl 2 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
lvl 3 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
```

Или это:

```
lvl 0 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
lvl 1 :1
lvl 2 :1
lvl 3 :1
```

Если с брейкпоинтами, то примерно вот это:

```
lvl 0 :1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10
lvl 1 :1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 9
lvl 2 :1 -> 6 -> 9
lvl 3 :1
```

Я пользуюсь CLion.

Код:

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SkipList.h"

int main()
{
    SkipList list{4, 1/4.0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.push(i + 1);
        list.out();
    }


    //list.out();
}
```

SkipList.h:

```
//
// Created by nail1 on 09.08.2018.
//

#ifndef INC_18_11_SKIPLIST_H
#define INC_18_11_SKIPLIST_H

struct intList
{
    int value;
    intList* next {nullptr};
};

class SkipList
{
    intList** lvls;
    int numb_lvls;
    double p;

    void pushInLvl(int numb, int val);
    void findPlace(intList **prev, intList **next, int numb, int val);
public:
    SkipList(int numb, double pp) : numb_lvls{numb}, p{pp} {lvls = new intList*[numb]{nullptr};}
    void push(int val);
    void out();
};


#endif //INC_18_11_SKIPLIST_H
```

SkipList.cpp:

```
//
// Created by nail1 on 09.08.2018.
//

#include "SkipList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

void SkipList::push(int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numb_lvls; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        double rand_numb = ( rand() % 101 ) / 100.0;

        if (i == 0 || !lvls[i] || rand_numb < p)
            pushInLvl(i, val);
        else
            return;
    }

}

void SkipList::pushInLvl(int numb, int val)
{
    intList* prev{nullptr};
    intList* next{nullptr};
    findPlace(&prev, &next, numb, val);

    intList* newMemb = new intList{val, nullptr};

    if (!prev && !next)
    {
        lvls[numb] = newMemb;
        return;
    }
    else if (!prev)
    {
        newMemb->next = next;
        lvls[numb] = newMemb;
        return;
    }
    else if (!next)
    {
        prev->next = newMemb;
        return;
    }
    else if (prev && next)
    {
        newMemb->next = next;
        prev->next = newMemb;
        return;
    }
}

void SkipList::findPlace(intList **prev, intList **next, int numb, int val)
{
    *prev = nullptr;
    *next = nullptr;
    intList* curLvl{lvls[numb]};

    if (!curLvl)
        return;
    else if(val < curLvl->value)
    {
       *next = curLvl;
        return;
    } else
    {
        *prev = curLvl;
        *next = curLvl->next;
        while (*next && (*next)->value < val)
        {
            *prev = *next;
            *next = (*next)->next;
        }
    }

}

void SkipList::out() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numb_lvls; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "lvl " << i << " :";
        intList* curLvl = lvls[i];
        while(curLvl)
        {
            std::cout << curLvl->value;
            if (curLvl->next)
                std::cout << " -> ";
            curLvl = curLvl->next;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если поставить брейкпоинт а затем убрать и продолжить работу программы в "нормальном" режиме, то тоже работает неправильно.

Comment: То есть программа работает правильно если пошагово "следить за ней".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `srand(time(NULL));` вызывается при каждом `push`, соответственно с большой долей вероятности запуская ту же последовательность случайных чисел, что и на предыдущем шаге. А брейкпоинты разбивают эти последовательные вызовы.

`srand` имеет смысл вызвать один раз на поток. Ну или использовать более продвинутые генераторы случайных чисел.

Answer (score 0):

В SkipList.h конструкторе вызываете

```
lvls = new intList*[numb]{nullptr};
```

Это не то, что вы думаете. Эту запись вообще нельзя делать. *(В стандарте нет.)* Инициализируется только `lvls[0] := nullptr;` Все остальные значения по-умолчанию забиваются нулём. Уберите `{nullptr}`. Делайте просто пустую инициализацию.

```
lvls = new intList*[numb]{};
```

Comment: Не ясно, что именно вы хотите сказать. Да, `nullptr` инициализирует только нулевой элемент массива, а все остальные инициализируются по умолчанию, что для указателей означает инициализацию на null-указатель. То есть в итоге эффект в точности идентичен для всех элементов массива. И он в точности совпадает с вашим вариантом с `{}`. То есть ваш вариант короче, но эффект во всех случаях один и тот же. С чего вы взяли, что "эту запись вообще нельзя делать" - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT Это предупреждение на следующие попытки так инициализировать массив. Любые попытки так инициализировать не нулевыми значениями потерпит крах. Типо я же вас предупреждал.